# Magento cart get price single item

Tags: cart, price, shopping-cart

I want to display the price excluding tax of a single item in the cart.
Therefore I need to edit the `app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`

How can I display the price of a single item?
I tried `<?php echo $item->getPrice();?>` but that did not work.

Comment: Did you try `$item->getProduct()->getPrice();`?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya Thanks! I tried that, but that is displaying the price including tax. How can I display it excluding tax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deduct tax amount from product price and then display it on cart page.

```
$priceExcludingTax = ($_item->getPrice() * $this->getQty()) - ($_item->getTaxAmount() * $this->getQty());
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but that does not seem to work. I get a php error, when trying to echo `<?php echo $priceExcludingTax;?>`

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks, I needed to change `$item` to `$_product`. But that is still displaying the price including tax.

Comment: Please check what values you get in `$item->getPrice()` and `$item->getTaxAmount()`

Comment: Thanks! I needed to change `$item` to `$_item`. But that is still not working. I want to price for 1 single item. When changing the value in the cart to two items, the price changes.

Comment: You can multiply with available quantity. Please check updated answer